# How to write parquet files from streaming query?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I'm reading from a CSV file using Spark 2.2 structured streaming.
My query for writing the result to the console is this:

```scala
val consoleQuery = exceptions
  .withWatermark("time", "5 years") 
  .groupBy(window($"time", "1 hour"), $"id")
  .count()
  .writeStream
  .format("console")
  .option("truncate", value = false)
  .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(10.seconds))
  .outputMode(OutputMode.Complete())
```

The result looks fine:

```
+---------------------------------------------+-------------+-----+
|window                                       |id           |count|
+---------------------------------------------+-------------+-----+
|[2017-02-17 09:00:00.0,2017-02-17 10:00:00.0]|EXC0000000001|1    |
|[2017-02-17 09:00:00.0,2017-02-17 10:00:00.0]|EXC0000000002|8    |
|[2017-02-17 08:00:00.0,2017-02-17 09:00:00.0]|EXC2200002   |1    |
+---------------------------------------------+-------------+-----+
```

But when writing it to a Parquet file

```scala
val parquetQuery = exceptions
  .withWatermark("time", "5 years")
  .groupBy(window($"time", "1 hour"), $"id")
  .count()
  .coalesce(1)
  .writeStream
  .format("parquet")
  .option("path", "src/main/resources/parquet")
  .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(10.seconds))
  .option("checkpointLocation", "src/main/resources/checkpoint")
  .outputMode(OutputMode.Append())
```

and reading it in with another job,

```
val data = spark.read.parquet("src/main/resources/parquet/")
```

the result is this:

```
+------+---+-----+
|window|id |count|
+------+---+-----+
+------+---+-----+
```

Comment: I _think_ `.withWatermark("time", "5 years")` and `.outputMode(OutputMode.Append())` are possible root cause of no output available. Can you `.withWatermark("time", "1 seconds")` instead and start over?

Comment: I changed to 1 second but still get the same results. I made the following additional observation: When changed to 1 second and dropped another csv file at the given place which contains data in one of the given time windows (but with another timestamp) I get data in the parquet file like this:

Comment: `+---------------------------------------------+-------------+-----+
|window                                       |id           |count|
+---------------------------------------------+-------------+-----+
|[2017-02-17 08:00:00.0,2017-02-17 09:00:00.0]|EXC2200002   |1    |
+---------------------------------------------+-------------+-----+`
But not from the other time windows. looks like that Append does only update or "close" those time windows that receive data with a timestamp newer that the last maximum.

Comment: That's my point exactly. `Append` is sensitive on watermark that says how long to wait till an aggregation is complete and could be passed on to a sink (like `console`). Why do you use `Append`?

Comment: What else can I use than Append? Using Complete or Update I get `Data source parquet does not support Update output mode`.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski anything new on the topic?

Comment: Did you check progress logs of the second stream? It should show how many input rows read. If it reads properly then try to delete checkpointing files to re-process input files. Are you dropping different csv files (name, content)? Or are you playing with one?

Comment: yep, did throw different files at it and saw numInputRows to be greater than 0. And before I do any test, I delete the checkpoint dir. I even reduced the sample to be less "complex" by reading only TXT files containing an id and a epoch timestamp. But to see it still looks like that processing events with a timestamp older than watermark do not force writing the parquet file.

Comment: Did you resolve this btw?

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR** `parquetQuery` has **not** been started and so no output from a streaming query.

Check out the type of `parquetQuery` which is [org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter) which is simply a description of a query that at some point is supposed to be started. Since it was not, the query has never been able to do anything that would write the stream.

Add `start` at the very end of `parquetQuery` declaration (right after or as part of the call chain).

```
val parquetQuery = exceptions
  .withWatermark("time", "5 years")
  .groupBy(window($"time", "1 hour"), $"id")
  .count()
  .coalesce(1)
  .writeStream
  .format("parquet")
  .option("path", "src/main/resources/parquet")
  .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(10.seconds))
  .option("checkpointLocation", "src/main/resources/checkpoint")
  .outputMode(OutputMode.Append())
  .start // <-- that's what you miss
```

Comment: Nope, I just left out the code which did start the query and the await in my question post. Starting and waiting was too obvious for beeing posted :-)

Comment: Show the entire code to start the streaming query (so I'm not pointing at things you've already figured out yourself). Thanks!

Comment: The missing code for running the query: `val runningQuery = parquetQuery.start
    runningQuery.explain
    runningQuery.awaitTermination`